# Command to search ffmpeg directory pathway

Tags: macos, command-line, video, ffmpeg

I'm new to ffmpeg and I am trying to convert some avi videos to uncompressed avi files.   The problem is every time I run the command:

```
ffmpeg -i "Dip 1.avi"
```

this error message appears:

```
Dip 1.avi: no such file or directory
```

I'm almost 100% sure that i've got the video in the wrong file and ffmpeg can't find it.

What I would like to know is what is the command line to search for the directory pathway within ffmpeg so I can put my video in the correct file?
I'm using the latest Mac operating system.

Comment: Where is the file "Dip 1.avi"? And in which directory are you know? Do you know shell basics?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the ffmpeg command from the commandline you could easily tell what is your working directory with the following command:

```
pwd
```

and you can also check the content of the current directory as well with:

```
ls -la
```

Answer (score 0):

`ffmpeg` doesn't support a "search path" for input files.  You must specify an exact path/filename.  If the file is in the current directory (the shell's current directory), you don't need to specify a path.  But, if your input file(s) are located in another directory, you must specify a path (absolute, like "`/Users/me/Videos/Dip 1.avi`", or relative, like "`Videos/Dip 1.avi`") to is an exact path to your file..